# Three.js При загрузке текстуры изображение стает размытым

Tags: three.js

addCube: function(w,h,d,x,y,imgs){
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(w, h, d);

```
        var materials = [
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( imgs[0], )
            }),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( imgs[1], )
            }),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( imgs[2], )
            }),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( imgs[3], )
            }),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( imgs[4], )
            }),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( imgs[5], )
            }),
        ];

        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
        cube.position.set(x,y,0);

        return cube;
    },
```

imgs - это массив с base64[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
слева исходное изображение, справа уже на фигуре, размытое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebGL` и `three.js` в свою очередь имеют под капотом алгоритмы фильтрации текстур, За выбор алгоритма и настройку отвечают следующие параметры у текстуры:

```
texture.magFilter : number
```

Алгоритм фильтрации, который работает когда тексель больше пикселя. значение по-умолчанию - `THREE.LinearFilter` - он берет 4 ближайших текселя и возвращает интерполированное значение, между ними **(отсюда у Вас размытие)**, Другой вариант это - `THREE.NearestFilter` - он возвращает ближайший тексель.

```
texture .minFilter : number
```

Алгоритм того, как текстура сэмплируется, когда тексель меньше пикселя `THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter` - используется [мипмаппинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIP-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и [трилинейная фильлтрация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```
texture.anisotropy : number
```

Кол-во сэмплов, которое будет сделано из текстуры для пикселей, в которые попало множество текселей, по умалчанию это значение = 1. Большие значения улучшают качество текстурирования, но стоят дополнительных сэмплов из текстуры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!